# TLS 1.2 downgraded to 1.1 in IIS 7

Tags: https, iis

When I connect to my website using Chrome 45 The SSL dealie tells me that it had to fallback to a less secure TLS. It says I connected at 1.1, but I know that the server is set up to do 1.2.

NMAP claims the following is supported by my web server:

```
|   TLSv1.1
|     Ciphers (7)
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
|     Compressors (1)
|       uncompressed
|   TLSv1.2
|     Ciphers (15)
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html claims the following is supported by my browser:

```
Cipher Suites (in order of preference)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   Forward Secrecy  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   Forward Secrecy    128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   Forward Secrecy    128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc14)   Forward Secrecy    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc13)   Forward Secrecy  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc15)   Forward Secrecy    256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   Forward Secrecy 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   Forward Secrecy   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   Forward Secrecy   256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   Forward Secrecy 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   Forward Secrecy   128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   Forward Secrecy   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) 112
```

I see overlap in both here: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

What gives, has anyone seen this before?

I suppose it could be a Chrome thing, but I can't find any existing mentions of this. I have a couple other webservers that do not have this issue, Chrome quite happily connects with them over TLS 1.2 using AES_128_GCM with DHE_RSA as the key exchange.

EDIT: IE being able to connect via TLS 1.2 (Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)) lends credence to this being an IIS playing with Chrome issue and not necessarily an IIS problem.

Comment: IE has no problem, so this looks like a Chrome issue.  I smell a bug coming :(

Comment: Try running an SSL test on your website; https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I'll try that on Monday.  This is also a potential lead: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74689/server-sends-rst-during-tls-handshake-why

Comment: Took a while to get an externally accessible server that matched the ones having issues... SSLTest had no issues connecting using TLS 1.1 and 1.2